# c# - Accessing MySQL server in Windows CE 6.0

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-ce

We were asked by a client to develop a barcode scanning system using their existing database which is in MySQL. We decided to use Visual Studio C# 2008 to develop it in their Handheld device (Motorola MC3190) running on Windows CE 6.0.

The problem is, what database can we use or how can we access the existing MySQL Server in Windows CE 6.0. We already searched for the answer but we couldn't find a proper one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the MySQL Connector, add a refrence to it, and use it like you would any other database (i.e. `DbConnection`, `DbCommand`, etc).

There was at one time (2009-ish) a bug in the connector - not sure if it's been fixed on not, so if you have trouble, [take a look at the workaround](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/05/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-on-the-net-compact-framework/).